# Node wrangler not working blender2.82a in Mac OS

Tags: system

I am using Mac Book air as my device and I am new to Blender.

Node wrangler shortcut like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>  or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>  bar doesn’t work as they coincide with the system shortcut eg. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>  in the node editor, instead of maximizing the view, it open up spotlight search of the system.

Because of this I am not able to use node such as temporary view, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for reading. For those with the same issue, there are two hotkeys for mac.

One with the combination of keys and mouse with <kbd>CMD</kbd> (similar to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> in windows) and another with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> instead of <kbd>CMD</kbd> in case it's in conflict with system hotkey.